# Project Euler Number 3

Tags: java

First of all, this isn't homework... working on this outside of class to get some practice with java.

```
public class Problem3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    int n = 13195;

    // For every value 2 -> n
    for (int i=2; i < n; i++) {
        // If i is a multiple of n
        if (n % i == 0) {
            // For every value i -> n
            for (int j=2; j < i; j++) {
                if (n % j != 0) {
                    System.out.println(i); 
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I keep modifying the code to try to make it do what I want.

As the problem says, you should be getting 5, 7, 13 and 29.

I get these values, plus 35, 65, 91, 145, 203, 377, 455, 1015, 1885, and 2639. I think I'm on the right track as I have all the right numbers... just have a few extras.

And in checking a few of the numbers in both being divisible by n and being prime numbers, the issue here is that the extra numbers aren't prime. Not sure what's going on though.

If anyone has any insight, please share.

Comment: "Play computer." Trace out the execution on paper, writing down loop values, the results of the math conditionals, etc. Alternatively, use a debugger, but IMO writing it down engages more of the brain.

Comment: Note that for the final question (600851475143), you will need to use `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: -1 One of the rule of project Euler is not to spread the answers.

Comment: @btoueg I don't see any answers, other than the ones that are provided on the problem page.

Answer (score 2):

This part

```
for (int j=2; j < i; j++) {
    if (n % j != 0) {
        System.out.println(i); 
        break;
    }
```

doesn't check whether `i` is prime. Unless `i` is small, that will always print `i` at some point, because there are numbers smaller than `i` that don't divide `n`. So basically, that will print out all divisors of `n` (It wouldn't print the divisor `4` for `n == 12`, for example, but that's an exception).

Note also that the algorithm - using `long` instead of `int` to avoid overflow - even if fixed to check whether the divisor `i` is prime for deciding whether to print it, will take a long time to run for the actual target. You should investigate to find a better algorithm (hint: you might want to find the complete prime factorisation).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in Java and looking at my solution the obvious advice is start using BigInteger, look at the documentation for java.math.BigInteger

Also a lot of these problems are "Math" problems as much as they are "Computer Science" problems so research the math more, make sure you understand the math reasonably well, before coming up with your algorithm. Brute force can work some times, but often there are tricks to these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Brut force can also work for checking whether factor is prime or not for this problem...
eg.

```
     for(i=1;i<=n;i++)// n is a factor.
      {
        for(j=i;j>=1;j--)
          {
             if(i%j==0)
              { 
                  counter++;// set counter=0 befor.
              }
             if(counter==2) // for a prime factor the counter will always be exactly two.
             {
                  System.out.println(i);
              }
              counter=0;   
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about Java but here is my C code if it is of any help.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>

// A function to print all prime factors of a given number n
void primeFactors(long long int n)
{
// Print the number of 2s that divide n
while (n%2 == 0)
{
printf("%d ", 2);
n = n/2;
}
int i;
// n must be odd at this point. So we can skip one element (Note i = i +2)
for ( i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i+2)
{
// While i divides n, print i and divide n
while (n%i == 0)
{
printf("%d ", i);
n = n/i;
}
}

// This condition is to handle the case whien n is a prime number
// greater than 2
if (n > 2)
printf ("%ld ", n);
}

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
{
long long int n = 600851475143;
primeFactors(n);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very good that you are working on such problems out of class. 
Saw your code. You are writing a procedural code inside main function/thread.
Instead write functions and think step by step algorithmically first.
The simple algorithm to solve this problem can be like this:

- 1) Generate numbers consecutively starting from 2 which is the least prime, to 13195/2. (Any number always has its factor smaller than half of it's value)
- 2) Check if the generated number is prime.
- 3) If the number is prime then check if it is factor of 13195;
- 4) Return the last prime factor as it is going to be the largest prime factor of 13195;

One more advice is try writting seperate functions to avoid code complexity.
Code is like this...

```
    public class LargestPrimeFactor {

public static long getLargestPrimeFactor(long num){

   long largestprimefactor = 0;

   for(long i = 2; i<=num/2;i++){

       if(isPrime(i)){

           if(num%i==0){


               largestprimefactor = i;

               System.out.println(largestprimefactor);

           }            
       }              
   }

   return largestprimefactor;

}

public static boolean isPrime(long num){

    boolean prime=false;
    int count=0;
    for(long i=1;i<=num/2;i++){

        if(num%i==0){


            count++;

        }
        if(count==1){

            prime = true;

        }
        else{

            prime = false;
        }           
    }

    return prime;

}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Largest prime factor of 13195 is "+getLargestPrimeFactor(13195));

}
```

}